# iOS - How to get params in One-Link of AppsFlyer. App was installed and launched

Tags: ios, swift, analytics, tracking, appsflyer

I can get params (campaign, media-source, etc...) of One-Link if my app does not install. I use the method below to do it.

```
func onConversionDataReceived(_ installData: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {

    if let data = installData{

        print("\(data)")

        if let status = data["af_status"] as? String{

            if(status == "Non-organic"){

                if let sourceID = data["media_source"] , let campaign = data["campaign"]{

                    print("This is a Non-Organic install. Media source: \(sourceID)  Campaign: \(campaign)")

                }

            } else {

                print("This is an organic install.")

            }

        }

    }

}
```

But if my app was installed, launched and then I click on another One-Link to open my app, I just get only this URL by the method below:

```
func onAppOpenAttribution(_ attributionData: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {

    if let data = attributionData{

        print("\(data)")

    }

}
```

So have any way to get params (campaign, media-source, etc...) in case my app available on a device?

Note: I used a short link.

Comment: Please provide an example of the short link

Comment: Do you use schemas or universal links for your project? https://www.appsflyer.com/blog/how-to-set-up-ios-9-universal-links-for-your-app/

Comment: This is an example config One-Link in my case:

Short link: https://abc.onelink.me/180096006/7g02c1b7

// Full link: https://abc.onelink.me/2347196006?pid=User%20invite&c=CMTT2019einvite&af_dp=abc%3A%2F%2F

Comment: @blindknight could you please turn on SDK debug logs: `AppsFlyerTracker.shared().isDebug = true`
And share the logs that the SDK emits when testing both scenarios:
1. A "good" scenario in which the detailed dictionary response is given.
2. A "bad" scenario in which on `link` key/value are returned
If you do not like to share those logs publicly you can send them to support@appsflyer.com with a short description and a link to this thread.

Comment: I updated new sdk (upgrade 4.7.3 to 4.8.12) and its work perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onAppOpenAttribution` is triggered every time you open the app from different deep-link (In your case the One-Link).

> I can get params (campaign, media-source, etc...) of One-Link if my app does not install.

Right, 1st time the two callbacks are triggered `onAppOpenAttribution` and `onConversionDataReceived`.

> But if my app was installed, launched and then I click on another One-Link to open my app

It can happen if you try to open the app from One-Link that not belongs to Appsflyer.

For example, this link (Universal Link) `https://rndemotest.onelink.me/7y5s/f78c46d5` will give you a media source, campaign etc. through `onAppOpenAttribution`, where `7y5s` is your One-Link ID defined in "ONELINK CONFIGURATION" section of the dashboard.

**[EDIT]**

Be sure you run latest AppsFlyer SDK version,

> Deep linking with short links for iOS Universal Links or Android App Links is only supported from SDK version 4.8.0

Generally, you should get a response as `{"link": "<URL>"}` for *Full link* a.e. `{"link":"https://abc.onelink.me/2347196006?pid=User%20invite&c=CMTT2019einvite&af_dp=abc%3A%2F%2F"}`

For One-Link, you should get all inforamtion contains media source, ... .

---

BTW here is a code snippet example how to handle `onAppOpenAttribution` response:

```
func onAppOpenAttribution(_ attributionData: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {

        var attDataString:String = ""
        var params = [String: String]()

        print("")
        print("<-------------------------------------------------->")
        print("onAppOpenAttribution is:")

        if let pid = attributionData[AnyHashable("pid")] as? String{
            attDataString.append("PID: " + pid + "\n\n")
            print(helper(module: "pid", message: pid))
        }

        if let is_retargeting = attributionData[AnyHashable("is_retargeting")] as? String{
            attDataString.append("is_retargeting: " + is_retargeting + "\n\n")
            print(helper(module: "is_retargeting", message: is_retargeting))
        }

        if let campaign = attributionData[AnyHashable("c")] as? String{
            attDataString.append("Campaign: " + campaign + "\n\n")
            print(helper(module: "campaign", message: campaign))
        }

        if let link = attributionData[AnyHashable("link")] as? String{
            attDataString.append("Link: " + link + "\n\n")
            print(helper(module: "link", message: link))
        }

        if let af_dp = attributionData[AnyHashable("af_dp")] as? String{
            attDataString.append("af_dp: " + af_dp + "\n\n")
            print(helper(module: "af_dp", message: af_dp))
        }
        print(attributionData)
        print("<-------------------------------------------------->")
        print("")

        //        dump(attributionData)
    }

func helper(module:String!, message:String!) -> String!{

        var sb:String = ""
        sb.append(" " + module + "=")
        var pad:Int = 17 - module.characters.count

        while  pad > 0 {
            pad-=1
            sb.append( " " )
        }
        sb.append(" " + message)

        return sb
    }
```

Comment: I updated new sdk (upgrade 4.7.3 to 4.8.12) and its work perfect. Thank you so much for your help!